# One of a group of things: "One of my cousin called me" or "One of my cousins called me"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, countable-nouns, noun-phrases

Why is it incorrect to say,

> "One of my cousin called me."

instead of

> "One of my cousins called me."

Comment: ”One of my cousins“, I don't know why, but I have read many such kind of things.

Comment: If something is *one of ____*, then it can only be one of many things.  "One of one thing" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @stangdon You native speaker could never thought about the non-native's confusion :).
If I haven't read so many, I might have the same question.
When I just want to say "my cousin called me", I would find "my cousins called me" a little wierd. I know the difference, I just give an example.

Comment: @马化腾 - I'm just curious: does your native language have plurals, and does it use them this way?  I speak a little German, Spanish, and French, and all of them would use the plural here exactly the same way.

Comment: @stangdon yes, my native language is English. This is one of my pet peeves. I'm trying to find a graceful, effective way to educate others about it.

Answer (score 1):

Break it down to pieces like this:

> I have five **cousins**. One of **them** called me.

Hence

> One of my **cousins** called me.

Or:

> One of my **cousins** (I have five of **them**! That's a lot!) called me.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, especially to a native speaker. But judging from the comments above it doesn't make sense to non-native speakers who don't have the same convention in their native languages. I'm looking for a grammatical explanation that can be used by a non-native speaker to make the correct choice.